# How to Mark a Lightningchart Cell

Tags: lightningchart

How to mark a LightningChart cell like this?

[image: Mark Lightningchart cell]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RectangleSeries` allows drawing rectangles inside the series area. At first glance this would sound to match your requirement.

However, if your intention is to align the rectangle to the gridlines, then this probably doesn't help much. In this case, I would like to learn more about your use case before drilling further.

```js
const { lightningChart, SolidFill, ColorRGBA } = lcjs

const chart = lightningChart().ChartXY({ disableAnimations: true })
  .setTitle('')
const series = chart.addLineSeries({
    dataPattern: {
        pattern: 'ProgressiveX',
        regularProgressiveStep: true,
    },
})

series.addArrayY([0,100,50,40,70,10,90])
chart.addLegendBox().add(chart)

//

const rectangleSeries = chart.addRectangleSeries()
const rectangleFigure = rectangleSeries.add({ x1: 1.5, x2: 2, y1: 20, y2: 40 })
  .setFillStyle(new SolidFill({ color: ColorRGBA(255, 0, 0) }))
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@arction/lcjs@3.4.0/dist/lcjs.iife.js"></script>
```